# Need some help properly sorting a BFS tree into two separate sublists

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, computer-science

I have the code

```
from collections import deque

def bubbles(physical_contact_info):
    """takes physical contact info about a group of people and determines the bubbles."""
    result = []
    contacted = []
    non_contacted = []

    adj = adjacency_list(physical_contact_info)
    j = 0
    print(j)
    print(adj)
    for x in range(len(adj)-1, -1, -1):
        info = dfs_tree(adj, j)
        print(info)
        i = len(info)-1
        while info[i] != None:
            contacted.insert(0, i)
            i = info[i]
            #print(i)
            #print(contacted)
        if info[i] == None:
            non_contacted.insert(0, i)
    
    if len(non_contacted) != 0:
        result.append(non_contacted)
    if len(contacted) != 0:
        result.append(contacted)
    return result
    
def adjacency_list(graph_str):
    """>"""
    splitted = graph_str.splitlines()


    header = splitted[0]
    number_of_vertices = int(header.split()[1])

    adjacent = [[] for vertex in range(number_of_vertices)]

    #check if weighted, directed
    if header[-1] == "W":
        is_weighted = True
    else:
        is_weighted = False
   
    if is_weighted:
        if header[0] == "D":
            for line in splitted[1:]:
                new_line = line.split()
                adjacent[int(new_line[0])].append((int(new_line[1]), int(new_line[2])))
        else:
            for line in splitted[1:]:
                new_line = line.split()
                adjacent[int(new_line[0])].append((int(new_line[1]), \
                int(new_line[2])))
                adjacent[int(new_line[1])].append((int(new_line[0]),\
                int(new_line[2])))


    else:
        if header[0] == "D":
            for line in splitted[1:]:
                new_line = line.split()
                adjacent[int(new_line[0])].append((int(new_line[1]), None))
        else:
            for line in splitted[1:]:
                new_line = line.split()
                adjacent[int(new_line[0])].append((int(new_line[1]), None))
                adjacent[int(new_line[1])].append((int(new_line[0]),None))
    return adjacent


def dfs_tree(adj_list, start):
    """."""
    number_of_vertices = len(adj_list)
    state = ["U" for i in range(number_of_vertices)]
    parent = [None for i in range(number_of_vertices)]
    state[start] = "D"
    new = dfs_loop(adj_list, start, state, parent)
    return parent


def dfs_loop(adj_list, u, state, parent):
    """."""
    for v, weight in adj_list[u]:
        if state[v] == "U":
            state[v] = "D"
            parent[v] = u
            dfs_loop(adj_list, v, state, parent)
    state[u] = "P"


physical_contact_info = """\
U 2
0 1
"""

print(sorted(sorted(bubble) for bubble in bubbles(physical_contact_info)))
#Should be returning [[0, 1]], currently getting [[0, 1], [1]]
```

I am trying to get everything so that at the end it will return a list consisting of two sublists, one of every vertex that is not connected to another ("Uncontacted" if you will) and another that contains every vertex that does have a connection to another ("Contacted"). I am having trouble getting the contents of the tree to insert into the proper lists, as I do not know what to do to get these vertices to append to the correct list. Help would be greatly appreciated!

### Other test cases

#### Case 1:

```
physical_contact_info = """  
U 2
"""

print(sorted(sorted(bubble) for bubble in bubbles(physical_contact_info)))
```

Output should be:

> `[[0], [1]]`

#### Case 2:

```
physical_contact_info = """  
U 7
1 2
1 5
1 6
2 3
2 5
3 4
4 5
"""

print(sorted(sorted(bubble) for bubble in bubbles(physical_contact_info)))
```

Output should be:

> `[[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]`

#### Case 3:

```
physical_contact_info = """  
U 0
"""

print(sorted(sorted(bubble) for bubble in bubbles(physical_contact_info)))
```

Output should be:

> `[]`

#### Case 4:

```
physical_contact_info = """  
U 1
"""

print(sorted(sorted(bubble) for bubble in bubbles(physical_contact_info)))
```

Output should be:

> `[[0]]`

Have been thinking of a `for` loop at the moment, but am still unsure if that would help or if it would be necessary.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: So far tried extracting it with a set instead of using a tree, along with trying to append the sublists into the greater list before inserting the vertices

Comment: Could you edit the code for that attempt into your post, as well as what went wrong?

Comment: originally it was something along the lines of for i in range(len(splitted)-1): physical_contact_info += splitted[i].split(" ")
and then
contacted = set(physical_contact_info[2:])
but im specifically supposed to have this as a BFS, which is where I struggle

Comment: Comments don't format code well. Could you edit the code for that attempt **into your post, including what went wrong**?

Comment: Edited it to the current version I have that uses a DFS instead of a BFS. Implemented that for loop which changed the result, but still not to what i want

Comment: *"return a list consisting of two sublists"*: why is this pair sorted in all your test cases (with the outer call to `sort`)? I don't see the benefit of potentially swapping the list of connected with the list of non-connected. I would expect the output to always have the non-connected first and connected second. How else can you interpret the output correctly? In some of your test cases, there is only one sublist. How can you know whether that sublist represents connected or non-connected nodes?

Comment: If this is related to a code challenge, it would be good if you would quote it. All your examples are undirected, unweighted graphs, yet you have code for directed and weighted graphs. What is expected to happen with those?

Comment: None of the examples concern graphs that have more than 2 connected components. What should happen for such cases?